# How to remove the maximum length of an array?

Tags: twig

I'm having some problems using twig.
When I try to bring an array to javascript, the array always returns the maximum length of 100.

i.e.

```
{% set getnumbers%}
    {% for number in numberLists %}
        {{number['odd'] | json_encode() }},
    {% endfor%}
{% endset%}
    
var getNumbers = [
    1,
    3,
    5 ...
    197,
    199
];
console.log (getNumbers);
```

On the console:

```
(100) [
1,
3,
5 ...
197,
199]
   length: 100
```

Also

```
 {{ numberLists | length }} returns = [100];
```

Although the length returns as 100, it is 100 numbers per page. the last number of the array should be 503.

I believe that the array is limited in some way due to the pagination that is set for every 100 elements.

this is the code for the pagination that is by default in the template

```
{% if pagination['count'] > 100 %}
                {% if searchList %}
                    {% set params = {} %}
                    {% for search in searchList %}
                        {% set params = params | merge([search['name'] ~ '=' ~ search['value']]) %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% set params = '?' ~ params|join('&') %}
                {% endif %}
```

I'm using a third-party system with an integrated API.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the back-end to be making any adjustments there, the only part I have access to, are the templates to configure some java, html and use some variables and arrays informed by the developer.

in the documentation provided by the developer, there is nothing relevant about this.

The dump function is appearing as unrecognized, from what I searched, it is not enabled by default, so it must be disabled.

Comment: There is no maximum length set by `twig` on "outputting" variables. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/ftseu2). Also if you want to use `twig` variables inside javascript you are better off with the filter [`json_encode`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html). Please start by verifying the variable with the debug function [`dump`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/dump.html) or `{{ numberLists | length }}`. You are also mentioning "pagination" but we don't know how the data is sent to the view. Please update your question with all the relevant information

Comment: As from your update: You have any idea on how to loop the pagination? I mean do you know the object they are sending? A solution would be to create a `TwigFunction` which could consume/fetch the whole result instead of only the "current" page of the pagination

Comment: It would be easier if you told us what third party you are using.